# Address Book in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have a contact in my address book wich is "info@company.com", whom name in address book is "Company"

This info e-mail, will be read by John, Olivia and Mark in different computers.

When I'm writing an e-mail address in "From", I'd like to write "John", and it pointed me to "info@company.com", the same as for Olivia and Mark, instead of write "Company".

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried creating a Contact for John, Olivia and Mark and add each one the company Mail Address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

In Outlook, go to the contact, right click and edit the properties.

In the Middle Name field (or an unused searchable field), enter each of the identifiers you would look for.

When you go to compose an email, you can type any of those names you entered, and it will pull up the "company" email address.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. "Company" is not my account, is someone account I have on my address book.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry for misunderstanding the question, I edited my answer to reflect my current understanding.